# Google Drive 'Make a copy' does not copy 'properties' metadata

Tags: google-drive-api, copy

When you right click and copy file from google drive, it does not copy the 'properties' metadata from old file.
[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy) says: 'Entries with null values are cleared in update and copy requests.'

Does this mean the default operation 'Make a copy', does not copy the 'properties' meta data from old file?

Comment: Is this a programming related question? [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that your question is related to the script because I confirmed the link to the method of "Files: copy" in Drive API. But from your replying `i can't use the copy method as that feature has to be done from UI(right click file-> 'Make a copy')`, I could understand that my understanding was not correct. So I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: its not your problem either. i should have mentioned it clearly..appreciate your quick reply!

Comment: @Rob my bad! you are right. its related to a bug in the drive API.

Comment: In this case, how about reporting it as a bug to [Google issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)? Because although I searched this issue at the Google issue tracker, unfortunately, I couldn't find about it.

Comment: Hey there, so let me understand more clearly - are you copying the file using the API or just the Drive UI? @user3900196

Comment: @ale13 just the Drive UI

Comment: @Tanaike i am going to report this. thanks!

Comment: Yep, I just ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are describing is **not** a bug, but the expected one when using the Drive UI.

For example, when copying a file, the `modified` and `accessed time` properties are expected to change.

As for the documentation you have posted, this refer copying a file when using the Drive API.

Comment: I curious how its not a bug. When i file is copied its metadata needs to be preserved. Date/Time is an exception, 'properties' meta data is just a key/value pair.
I have reported this to google issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158103572